# UILocalNotification scheduled in background doesn't fire

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have an app that runs in the background using location services (via Significant Location updates). Whenever a significant location is updated, `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` gets called and I then call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:...` to start my background task. Next, I try to fire a local notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[notif setAlertAction:@"Test"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notif];
```

However, no notification gets presented to the user. Are local notifications not able to be sent from the background? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you verified that your background task is completing? Where exactly are you scheduling the local notification, is it in some kind of completion block? And yes you can send them from the background. I suspect something else is wrong with the code you're referring to.

Comment: Maybe your app is not in the background. Did you check if the app delegate's `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` is called instead?

Comment: @PeterFoti There is no completion block. I schedule the local notification in the didUpdateLocations method right after I call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that your background fetching is in fact working? Also, to be thorough, are you running on a device and not a simulator?

Comment: I have verified that my background fetching is working, but I just realized that I do not call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];` when I am done with the task. Could this fix my problem?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ? It seems I'm not able to schedule a notification from a significant location change.

Comment: Francescu, this seems to be a bug. My solution is to just schedule a local notification for .1 seconds from now.

Answer (score 1):

You need fire date:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = text;
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.repeatInterval = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Comment: From Apple docs: `The fire date is interpreted according to the value specified for timeZone. If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the notification is delivered immediately.`

Comment: yes, this code is work with my project. I use it to post localnotification. you can try it.